# Nuxt 3 @sidebase - Authenticate API request using a bearer token

Tags: oauth, token, nuxtjs3, nuxt-auth

I'm trying to build an app using Nuxt 3 and [sidebase](https://sidebase.io/). I implemented an API and integrated the KeycloakProvider as an Nuxt authentication provider. When logging in from the integrated Vue frontend Nuxt automatically creates a server session and thus I'm authenticated and able to use the API. However if an external client wanted to use the API by sending a bearer token with every request, neither Nuxt nor sidebase seem to offer an out of the box solution to validate bearer tokens, for example through the KeycloakProvider.
So I had to write a bearer token validator myself and add it to my authentication middleware.

I would have expected that the auth library from sidebase would ship some kind of validation function for bearer tokens. But I can't seem to find one.

Is there really nothing in existence at the moment, or am I missing something?